# CSS/JS collapsible div working in JSFiddle, not in browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having a bit of a problem here.

I am trying to make a collapsible div (think a folder tree-like thing) using the code at jsfiddle.net/cpkDg/

The code is working fine there, but when I try to integrate it into my site (a webapp) it's not working - http://dev.brandeer.ro/consins/standard/home.php

I am using Pushy (christopheryee.ca/pushy/) for the side menu, and I suspect that this is the culprit, but I have no idea how to test it in JSFiddle (copy-pasting the script - Modernizr et al) in JSFiddle didn't work).

I am only interested in this working on Chrome, since it is a webapp which will run only in Android WebView. In the near future I hope to implement it as a native app.

Do you have any idea how I could solve this ? I have been looking for a few days on a pure css version of a collapsible menu but it seems that everyone prefers JavaScript/jQuery implementations.

Comment: It seems to work on FireFox.

Comment: In Chrome too. What specifically does not work -- what do you observe and what do you want to observe?

Comment: Ctrl-F5 seems to be a problem of cache.

Comment: What behavior do you see, and what behavior do you expect?

Comment: On the JSFiddle it works fine, but on the mobile app it doesn't work at all. I'd expect that when I click the "Listelem" text in the side menu (click the icon to reveal it) another green div with the "Subelem" text in it should reveal itself.

I have tried clearing cache, not working.